# How in Jquery do I select the first blank input which is not a check box or a button

Tags: jquery

How in Jquery do I select the first blank input which is not a check box or a button. I have the following:

```
$(':input[value="",type!="button",type!="checkbox"]:visible:first').focus();
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tiny bit shorter

```
$("input[value='']:not(:checkbox,:button):visible:first").focus();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked. Btw u seem to know jquery pretty well... is there a good reference of syntax,rules,etc. I usually use the API reference from the jquery site but this particular scenario was not covered there.

Comment: np. I mainly use the jQuery reference online. However I also bought the jQuery 1.4 Reference Guide book and read through that just so I would have a better knowledge of the features available in jQuery. I also check this blog (http://webdevtweets.blogspot.com/) quite often, where Elijah Manor frequently posts links to good jQuery articles.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#formid')
  .find('input:blank:not(:checkbox,:button)')
  .filter(":visible:enabled")
  .first()
  .focus();
```

(During my testing, `input[value='']` worked only for pre-filled empty input fields; `input:blank` didn't have that problem.)

Comment: for me as well. I had to do the same what you did.

Comment: Note that `:blank` is part of of a jQuery validation plugin.  It's not standard jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

**UNTESTED**

```
$('input').not('input[type!="checkbox"],input[type!="button"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[value='']:not([type='checkbox'], [type='button']):visible:first").focus()
```

js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ft2Nh/